# mvn pact:verify does not execute provider state but @State code is executed from IDE

Tags: maven, pact, pact-jvm

When I execute my provider test from IDE @State method is executed, but mvn pact:verify command does not execute the @State of the provider

Provider test class:

```
@RunWith(PactRunner.class)
@Provider("wProvider")
@PactFolder("/home/username/workspace/automation/pactProject/pacts/")
public class WpproviderTest {

     @State("wProvider will create new stuff")
    public void providerState(){
         System.out.println("execute the the provider state");

         //some code...

        System.out.println("your new stuff response is: " + jsonResponse)   
    } 

     @TestTarget
    public final Target target = new HttpTarget(url, true);

    @TargetRequestFilter
    public void updateAuthHeaders(HttpRequest request) {
        request.addHeader("some auth headers")
    }
}
```

my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
    <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <serviceProviders>
            <serviceProvider>
                <name>wProvider</name>
                    <requestFilter>
                        request.addHeader('Authorization', 'auth value')
                    </requestFilter>
                    <stateChangeRequestFilter>
                        request.addHeader('Authorization', 'auth value')
                    </stateChangeRequestFilter>
               <stateChangeUrl>http://mywebsite.com/myservice/myaction
                            </stateChangeUrl>
                            <stateChangeUsesBody>true</stateChangeUsesBody>
                            <protocol>http</protocol>
                            <host>http://localhost</host>
                            <path></path>
                            <port>443</port>
                            <pactBroker>
                                <url>https://mypactbroker</url>
                                <authentication>
                                    <username>my_usrname</username>
                                    <password>my_pwd</password>
                                </authentication>
                            </pactBroker>
                            <insecure>true</insecure>
                        </serviceProvider>
                    </serviceProviders>
</plugin>
```

my pact file:

```
{
    "provider": {
        "name": "wProvider"
    },
    "consumer": {
        "name": "tConsumer"
    },
    "interactions": [
        {
            "description": "A new interaction with wProvider",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "path": "/somePath",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "body": ""
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "body": " ",
                "matchingRules": {
                    "body": {
                        // some matching rules
                    }
                }
            },
            "providerStates": [
                {
                    "name": "wProvider will create new stuff"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "pactSpecification": {
            "version": "3.0.0"
        },
        "pact-jvm": {
            "version": "3.6.7"
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute mvn pact:verify -X command I see in console:

Given Wprovider will generate new stuff

> [DEBUG] Invoked state change http://mywebsite.com/myservice/myaction
>   -> HTTP/1.1 200 OK [DEBUG] State Change: "ProviderState(name=http://mywebsite.com/myservice/myaction,
>   params={})" -> Ok(value={})

I am missing some settings related to @State with mvn pact:verify?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `@State` annotation isn't supported for the Maven plugin (unlike the JUnit setup).

The [docs](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/pact-jvm-provider-maven#provider-states) have the following to say about this:

> For each provider you can specify a state change URL to use to switch the state of the provider. This URL will receive the providerState description and parameters from the pact file before each interaction via a POST.

So you may need to add a dynamic endpoint (e.g. `/_pact/state`) that can take the request and setup the given state.

Comment: I agree with this, if maven plugin is used then and endpoint (presumably in the provider application) is needed to handle/take  state request.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven plugin (as well as the Gradle one) execute the Pact verification against a running provider when you execute `pact:verify`. The `@State` method you have defined is for a JUnit test. The Maven plugin does not execute JUnit tests, you run them as part of the `test` Maven phase which is executed by the Maven Surefire plugin.

The documentation link that Matt provided above will let you know how to execute state changes with `pact:verify`, but if you have written a JUnit test you don't need to use that.